# Grails-Spring Security loop hole: URL bypassing with [dot]

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, request-mapping

We have implemented access to Controller and actions with requestmap.
let's say URL like [www.example.com/car/list](http://www.example.com/car/list) access to ROLE_ADMIN.
but this resource is able to bypass spring security if we try URL like [www.example.com/adsf.car/list](http://www.example.com/adsf.car/list)

requestMap looks like this: /car/** -> ROLE_ADMIN

How to prevent from URL like in the above example from by-passing sprint security check?

I tried changing request map to /*car/** -> ROLE_ADMIN, but we have hindered of links like this, we cannot update pattern for all of them.

Comment: Is your question, how to prevent this?  Could you share an example?

Comment: Can you show your whole `requestMap`?

Comment: which plugin are you using? unable to duplicate with BeAPI.

Comment: Without seeing any code, I suspect this is not an actual Spring Security issue but an issue with one of the Grails API plugins or a REST handler(?). I can't duplicate this in the BeAPI plugin (which I maintain) as the communication and business logic are separate so an issue like this will NEVER happen.

Comment: Are you saying that a request to `/adsf.car/list` returns the same content as a request to `/car/list`?  The patter /car/** shouldn't protect `/adsf.car/list`.

Comment: It did not protect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution we found is that by adding constraints in the URLMappings. Allowing only alphabets,number and '_','/' in the request url.

Without below constraints, anybody can bypass URL protected with spring security requestMap by adding [dot] to controller or action.

```
"/$controller/$action?"{
    constraints {
        controller(matches:/[A-Za-z0-9\-_]*/)
        action(matches:/[A-Za-z0-9\-_]*/)
    }
 }
```

**NOTE: If you are using Spring Application and using request map to protect access to your resources then check if they are safely protected by adding [dot] to controller and action**

Comment: Still this definitely is a bug and should be addressed by the Grails team; EVERYONE should not be having to put in these constraints because of this. You should submit this as an issue to the Grails team and/or use the Beapi Plugin(https://github.com/orubel/Beapi-API-Framework) until this gets fixed